# Processing.js doesn't allow external javascript bind in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, processing.js

I'm trying to send data to a processing script. But for some reason the variable pjs below binds to the canvas "competence1" and enters the first if statement, but then the bindJavascript(this)-call returns error, but only in firefox. (works perfectly in chrome):

[pjs.bindJavascript is not a function]

```
var bound = false;
function initProcessing(){

    var pjs = Processing.getInstanceById('competence1');

        if (pjs != null) {

        // Calling the processing code method
        pjs.bindJavascript(this);
        bound = true;

        //Do some work
    }
    if(!bound) setTimeout(initProcessing, 250);
}
```

Environment: Mac OS X - Lion;
OBS! The bindJavascript(this)- method exists in the pde script loaded in the canvas-tag

Comment: I have found out the solution to my problem, since JS works with one thread the code above has other values by the time the time the pjs is suppose to bind in firefox. Since the setTimeout function needs to be approximately 2000 ms for firefox to bind properly every time as suppose to chrome whom does this reliably with the above setting, i can only conclude that firefox is a lot less efficient in it's operation.

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping up all my script in a varable-map and by using the second way for setTimeout to be called i can follow each state and control the result.

So wrap it up-->

```
var ex = {
    init : function(canId){
        var canId = canId;
        // check the if bound 
        // bind in this closure
        // set new timer
    }
}
```

setTimeout-->

```
setTimeout('ex.init("'+canId+'")', 2000);
```

and ofcourse add the parameter in so it can hold that value during it's own execution. So processing works just fine and i should use closure more often, that's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using almost identical JS to you (which I got from the Pomax tutorial), and it was working fine. However, when I added the following preload directive (to load a backdrop), then suddenly my initProcessing function stopped working.

```
/* @pjs preload="metal_background.jpg"; */
```

The error message was the same:  **pjs.bindJavascript is not a function**

On debugging, I could see that the pjs object did indeed not have a bindJavaScript function exposed, even though there is one declared in my PDE file.

It turns out this was purely down to timing... the preload had slowed down the initialisation of the processing object, so the second time round the 250ms loop, the pjs object existed, but didn't yet have its bindJavaScript function.

I am not 100% sure how Processing.js does this object construction, but in this case, a simple solution was just to check whether bindJavaScript actually was defined! I changed my code to the following:

```
        var bound = false;
        function initProcessing() {
            var pjs = Processing.getInstanceById('mySketchId');

            if(pjs != null) {

                if(typeof(pjs.bindJavaScript) == "function") {
                    pjs.bindJavaScript(this);
                    bound = true;
                }
            }

            if(!bound) setTimeout(initProcessing, 250);
        }
```

After this it worked fine!